# How can I stop my database from submitting an extra user?

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a successful PHP form that submits a user and their information to my database. With that being said before I hit the submit button a blank user is being added to the database.

Here is a photo to show a [before photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz2KJ.png)

Here is a photo to show me going to my [add.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaQQk.png)

Here is an [after photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fAvd.png)

You can see that two new users have been created.

Here is my code for my add.php

```
<?php
include_once('mysql.php');

$ins= "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, phone) 
VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[phone]')";

if ($conn->query($ins) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $ins . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href='index.php'>Home</a><br>

<h2>Add User</h2>

<form action="/add.php" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" >
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" >
  <br>
  Phone number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="phone" >
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Use `!empty()` against inputs and `isset()` on a submit, then query. You'd also might want to not allow empty values in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the page there is nothing to stop the PHP code from running, so a blank user is placed in the database. Do this instead:

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname') {
    $ins= "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, phone) 
VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[phone]')";

    if ($conn->query($ins) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $ins . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }
}
```

It would be better if you named your submit button and then tested that before running the queries, but this should get you started.

**WARNINGS**

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!